# REGEX - links vs hashtags conflict

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm using some regex to convert links, hashtags, mention etc from text I get from APIs (twitter, facebook,..)

It works well but in the special case where there is an anchor **#** in a link, the first pattern converts the link first and then the hastag inside the **link** tag - for example converting:

http://www.mytaratata.com/emission/taratata-n89/video/557/edwyn-collins-a-girl-like-you-1995#newsletter

is a mess.

I just would like the regex for twitter hashtags doesn't match if it's a link - (for exemple if it contains a dot)

```
hello#music -> match
#hello#music -> match
hello.com#music -> no match
```

I'm about something like this using a negative lookahead but I can't get it :

```
((?!\.)#.*\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)
```

Comment: I do not see the point in using `.*` if you want to match a string without a dot. Just use [`^(#[^.]*\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/bH4fZ5/2), it will never accept a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^(?!.*?\.).*?(#.*\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)
```

Get the hasttag from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uR1mF4/3)

**OR**

```
^.*?\..*$|(#\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uR1mF4/5)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping things simple here using this regex:

```
^[^.\n]+#([^#.\n]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY1rB5/2)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try to improve it but in the case of sentence#newsletter.#hello it's not precise enought

Comment: actually just #hello (and #newsletter)

Comment: btw `sentence#newsletter.#hello` doesn't even match Avinash's regex

Comment: If inputs with dots are to be allowed then you need much robust logic to detect a link, just checking for presence of DOT is not enough.

Comment: yes that's what I was checking writing it :), but I think I can play with both answers to find the good regex, I was just stucked before, thank you for your quick help again

Comment: yes the regex for links is more complex, but the same regex as a negative lookahead was impossible so I was just looking for a small trick for the special case of an anchor link

Comment: Hmm in that case [`^[^.\n#]*\..*$|#([^#.\n]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zY1rB5/3) would probably work better.